# How to go about storing multiple values from a loop, and displaying asterisks based on input

Tags: c#

This question asks to write a program that accepts input for five 'stores'. The input should ideally be a range from 100 to 2000. Each input should be divided by 100, and have that amount displayed in asterisks (i.e. 500 is *****, etc.). I believe I have the first part, but I've got no idea how to go about doing the rest. I cannot use arrays, as I have not learned them yet, and I want to be learn this myself instead of just copy-pasting from another student. So far, I only have

```
int loop;
loop = 1;

while (loop <= 5)
{
    string input1;
    int iinput1, asteriskcount1;
    Console.WriteLine("Input number of sales please!");
    input1 = Console.ReadLine();
    //store value?

    loop = loop + 1;
    input1 = Convert.ToInt32(input1);
    asteriskcount1 = iinput1 / 10;
}
```

Comment: Two homework question in an hour? Sounds like you should do some reading.

Comment: I've actually been struggling through six of these in the past 5 hours. I was able to do the other four using the book without problems, but I just couldn't figure out those two

Comment: I am glad this site didn't exist when I was studying Computer Science. Part of the learning process for writing code is trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. But maybe this will help. This is untested, but it should do what I THINK you are asking, but I am unsure what you wanted done with the asterisks. Please explain more if this isn't what you were getting at.

```
    string Stored = "";
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++;)
    {
        string input1;
        int iinput1, asteriskcount1;
        Console.WriteLine("Input number of sales please!");
        input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        //Adds to existing Stored value
        Stored += input1 + " is "; 

        //Adds asterisk
        iinput1 = Convert.ToInt32(input1);
        asteriskcount1 = iinput1 / 100;
        for(int j = 0; j < asteriskcount1; j++)
        {
             Stored += "*";
        }

        //Adds Comma
        if(i != 4)
             Stored += ",";

    }
    Console.WriteLine(Stored); //Print Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Super easy

```
int asteriskCount = int.Parse(input1)/ 100;
string output = new string('*', asteriskCount );
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to write it out for you but here's some thoughts ...

first, you can do a for loop for the 5 stores:

```
for (int loop = 0; loop < 5; loop++)
```

You'll probably want asterickCount (not asterickCount1) since you're in a loop.  You'll also want to divide by 100 since you're range is up to 2000 and you have 80 chars on a console.  That means it will print up to 20 astericks.

You'll want a PrintAstericks(int count); function that you call right after calculating the asterickCount that you call.  That function simply loos and calls Console.Write (not WriteLine) to write an asterick n times (new string has overload to take char and count).

But, that pattern will print the astericks after you take each input.  If you want the pattern to be (1) accept the counts for the five stores and then (2) print the asterick rows for all five, you'll need an array with 5 slots to store the inputs then loop through the array and print the asterick rows.

Finally, you'll want to put some validation on the inputs.  Look at Int32.TryParse:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx